# Give my browser a global variable accessible via javascript

Tags: java, javascript, applet, global-variables, system-variable

I have a POS web application which currently executes a java applet on page load. I don't want the java applet to be loaded on any computer that doesn't have the display pole for which it was made. The easiest way I can think of to get around this is to have the element disabled and re-enable it via javascript if a variable is "true". The javascript should be given a global variable somehow, which will let it know to activate the applet.

The question therefore is: Is there a way to set a global javascript variable from within the browser or OS? I originally wanted to use system variables but that apparently requires ActiveX controls.

Comment: Global variables can be set/changed by anyone. This is not a secure solution.

Comment: This has practically nothing to do with security. The applet just sends data to a serial port for display. Any PC that is running the web app has "permission" to use the applet; it's just that only ONE of the computers has a pole display to actually make USE of the applet. I only want to know whether or not to load the applet at all (again, not in lieu of security reasons).

Comment: I think the answer to this is No: browsers are intended to be sandboxed. There is [a question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8884347/using-javascript-in-hta-file-to-read-write-from-windows-registry) about reading Registry values which might be useful, but that requires ActiveX to break out of the sandbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a workable solution was to run the applet and have the applet check the name of the computer (http://bytes.com/topic/java/answers/699529-get-host-name-run-applet). After I have that, I had the applet close itself (`System.exit(0)`) and that pretty much solves any issues of hanging applets over a long period of time. It doesn't solve the issue completely but it's a good place to be in for now.

Comment: *"`System.exit(0)`) and that pretty much solves any issues of hanging applets"*  If the JRE permitted it, it can end not just the applet and page, but close the browser (I have seen it happen)!   Calling `System.exit(0)` is not a solution, but a dead-end.

Comment: What do you propose as an alternative to quitting the applet instance?

Comment: It is not an 'alternative' to `System.exit(n)` but the **correct** way to end an applet is to call [`AppletContext.showDocument(URL)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL%29) Where the `URL` points to `"ThanksFosUsingOurApplet.html"`.  I answered your question, now you answer mine.  Have you tried calling `System.exit(n)` in an applet **in a browser** yet?  What happened?

Comment: It closed properly. I have the console running whenever java is open and it closed right away which is what I wanted. I also checked the task manager and java closed. I'm using the latest release of Firefox.

Comment: ..hmm.  Next verion of FF, another OS, or another browser and you might see different behavior, especially if the applet is in a page that shares a VM with other applets.  You must have knocked the security manager out, BTW, or did you set a custom security manager?

Comment: IE v9 and latest Chrome was just tested and the same result: Java closes. I'm running Windows 7 x64 FWIW. I wouldn't doubt that other pages with Java running would be interrupted but that isn't a problem that needs consideration at the POS. As for the security manager, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. You can see the code I used for the applet at the following URL (sans System.exit(0)).  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7998523/just-trying-to-write-data-to-a-serial-port-from-a-java-applet

Answer (score 0):

See my answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11014753/restore-focus-to-java-applet-when-browser-tab-gains-focus/11016763#11016763). It is not *exactly* what what you wanted, but you might wait in your Applet until a method is called.
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

From my ..scan of the problem description, given you failed to ask a question I will presume one.

Have a 'hidden applet' the check for the ability to do ..whatever, and on failure, call a script that says/stores 'no'.  That script might then communicate with the applet to let it know how to appear, or what to do.